# A Venn Diagram Problem Given That $P(A \cap B)=.18$ and $P(A \cap B^C)=.22$

Tags: probability

I am having solving this question.

Given that $P(A \cap B)=.18$ and that $P(A \cap B^C)=.22$ Find $P(A)$.
Not sure how to do this

I get that $P(B)=1-.22=.78$ and then you do $1-.78=.6$ to get the only B in the Venn diagram. But I am not sure how to find $P(A)$

Comment: $$A = A \cap (B\cup B^c) = (A\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap\overline{B})=A\cap(B\cup\overline{B})=A\cap U=A$$
where $U$ is the universal set. Also note that $A\cap B$ and $A\cap\overline{B}$ are mutually exclusive sets.

Comment: Note in particular that this union is disjoint.

Comment: so just add the two sets which are mutually exclusive

Comment: Yeah. If you add these probabilities you will get $P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

$A=(A \cap B)\cup (A \cap B^C)$

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Venn diagram with sets $A$ and $B$ intersecting.

Let, for example, $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$, $B = \{ 2, 3 \}$ and the universal set $U = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$.

Then, $A \cap B^{C} = \{ 1, 2 \} \cap \{ 1, 4 \} = \{ 1 \}$; and so, since $A \cap B = \{ 2 \}$,

$$P(A) = P(A \cap B^{C}) + P(A \cap B) = .22 + .18 = .40$$